# Error on pushing a Nuget-Package (error creating the web proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultproxy' configuration section)

Tags: .net, asp.net, nuget, nuget-package

I receive the error

> "error creating the web proxy
>   specified in the
>   'system.net/defaultproxy'
>   configuration section"

if i try to push a package to nuget.

Heres is the commandline

> nuget push -source
>   http://packages.nuget.org/v1/
>   EmptyTestPackage.1.0.0.0.nupkg

How can i handle that ?

Comment: I've never seen this error. Can you file a bug on codeplex? http://nuget.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create. What kind of environment are you running in (is there a proxy, are things restricted)?

Comment: Please do not use the "ASP" tag if your question is about ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Is this a laptop that you carry back from work to home? AKA a situation where you have a default proxy set for work and you are trying this at home?